# SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unrecognized_name on OpenJDK

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, java

I'm having issues connecting to a server that is sending a wildcard certificate, i.e. `*.domain.whatever`.

It's able to establish a connection on machines with the Oracle JDK installed, while on a machine with OpenJDK it throws an `SSLHandshakeException` with the message in the title: looks like the JDK is not able to match the host name with the wildcard specified in the certificate.

I tried with the suggested solution I found elsewhere on the internet, which is to start the application with `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` to disable the JRE extension that handles hostname verification in SSL connections, but looks like this is not working on OpenJDK.

What am I missing? Is there a way to allow my application to connect properly to this server, assuming that not using OpenJDK and having that server use a non-wildcard certificate are not viable options?

Comment: It would be helpful if you add `-Djavax.net.debug=true` to your startup properties and add the output to your question

Comment: Maybe the certificate is not trusted on your machines using OpenJDK. Check what your truststore contains (with a keytool command) and add the authority's certificate if necessary.

Comment: This is **not about cert matching** (much less cert trust @Eugene) in the client. It is an alert from the _server_ (before any certificate is even sent) because the **server dislikes the SNI value sent**. That sysprop should disable sending SNI to the server (NOT client checking) in OpenJDK the same as in Oracle, but look at the debug output (`javax.net.debug=ssl` may be a _little_ less verbose) to be sure. There were bugs affecting SNI in some versions; exactly what versions of Oracle and OpenJDK are you running on?